# C++ string class that provides `slice` operations (doesn't create new string copy)

Tags: c++, string, slice

Are there existing C++ string class that provides slice operations and doesn't create new string copy? (kind of like [`string`](http://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_12.) in `go` programming language)

```
awesome::CString s = "this is an awesome string";
awesome::CString s1 = s.Mid(8, 10); // contains "an awesome" but not new copy
if (s1 == "an awesome") {
    awesome::CString s2 = s.Mid(11); // contains " string"
}
std::string str = s.str(); // create a copy that is the usual string
```

I'm thinking that go's implementation is more efficient for parsing a string data (e.g. parsing `APDU`)

Comment: by `not creating a copy` you want that changes to `s` reflects to `s1`? More specifically, `s1` just referencing to that portion of `s`?

Comment: yes changes will reflect, yes it is always a portion of original awesome string.

Comment: Traditionally such a design goes with immutable reference counted buffers (or COW buffers).  But C++1y/1z `string_view` is a non-owning view into a different string, and matches most of your description.

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a quick though and I believe a class storing a reference may be the best solution.

This does not behave exactly as you wish, because a temporary copy is still made to give you the substring. But the result is as expected, and I think it balances between safety and readability, not using hacks and such because the STL explicit says to not make assumptions on underlying string storage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class stringRef {
   public:
    string & src;
        size_t i;
        size_t s;
        stringRef(string &ssrc, size_t i_pos, size_t i_spam):src(ssrc){
            i=i_pos;
            s=i_spam;
        }
        operator const string(){
        return string(src.substr(i, s));
        }
    };

int main() {
    string s("this is an awesome string");
    stringRef s1(s, 8, 10);       //initializes [s1] bound to [s]
    cout << (string)s1 << endl;   //prints [s1]
    s=" quite a cool workaround"; //modifies [s]
    cout << (string)s1 << endl;   //prints [s1]
    return 0;
}
```

Will output:

```
an awesome
 cool work
```

From that you can improve the class to do whatever you wish =)

Comment: Not a good idea: one can easily end up to with a reference to a deleted string object.

Comment: That's a good point and I'm aware, but, well, it's not a full implementation, just an idea for the unanswered question. But I've just reread the question and `existing C++ string class` damm, I'm so sloppy. Hope it's helpful anyway.

Comment: @Michael: One can just as easily end up with references to deleted objects by using normal references. Does that make references a bad idea?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: references should be used only in a way that guarantees that the referenced object survives longer than reference. For example, function args can be references, or private members that reference data that can only be deleted by the class that has the member reference. Let me add another answer to OP's question in a minute that demonstrates that.

Comment: @michael beware that we are watching closely and will try very hard to beak your code =D

Comment: @Kahler: since I typed it in directly you won't have any problems with your noble endeavour. :)

Comment: @Michael: Well, you can apply the same rule to this class. Only use it in a way that guarantees it outlives the string it references. By the way, would you also say that [`llvm::StringRef`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html), [`boost::string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html) are not good ideas? What about [`string_view`](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3921.html), soon to be `std::string_view`?

Answer (score 0):

```
class AwesomeString {
private:    
    struct AwesomeData {
        std::string str;
        size_t refcnt;

        AwesomeData( const char *that ) {
            str = std::string(that);
            refcnt = 1;
        }
    };

    AwesomeData *data;
    size_t from, to;

public:
    AwesomeString( const char *str ) {
        data = new AwesomeData(str);
        from = 0;
        to = data->str.length();
    }

    AwesomeString( const AwesomeString &other, size_t begin, size_t end) {
        // Here is where the interesting part begins:
        data = other.data; // reference the same data
        data->refcnt++; // increment reference count
        from = begin;
        to = end;
    }

    ~AwesomeString() {
        data->refcnt--; // decrement reference count
        if(refcnt == 0) {
            // delete data on deletion of the last object that references it
            delete data; 
        }
    }

    operator const string() {
        return data->str.substr(from, to);
    }
};
```

The point I am trying to make here that pointers/references point to objects with well-controlled lifetime: the pointer data to AwesomeData is guaranteed never to point to a deleted object.

Comment: Something like this (fully implemented) is also a good idea. But the safety isn't free. Classes like this have their place, but so do string_ref-like classes.  By the way, why are you reimplementing reference counting rather than just using `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: you are right, this is essentially std::shared_ptr style implementation. I implemented reference counting explicitly here for a demonstration. In the real world out there std::shared_ptr should be used rather than reinvented. Besides, shared_ptr is thread-safe; AwesomeString is not.